Pywinauto throwing an MemoryError on Windows 11 but not on Windows 10
I have this code that works properly on windows 10 that I use to send text and enter keys to a specific window using pywinauto, but once i tried to use it in another system using win 11 it does not work.
Here is the code:
import pywinauto
import time

boolBisCheckbox = False
def parar(eachFfox):

    global boolBisCheckbox
    if boolBisCheckbox == False:
        appname = r"\[FIREFOX " + eachFfox + r"\]"
    else:
        appname = r"\[FIREFOX " + eachFfox + r"2\]"
    handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_window(title_re=appname)
    app = pywinauto.application.Application(backend="win32").connect(handle=handle)
    Wizard = app[appname]
    Wizard.send_keystrokes("parar")
    time.sleep(0.5)     
    Wizard.send_keystrokes("{ENTER}") 
    time.sleep(6) 
    Wizard.send_keystrokes("{ENTER}")
    time.sleep(10) 
    Wizard.send_keystrokes("{ENTER}")
input()
parar("A")

And here is the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pypy\testParar.py", line 23, in <module>
    parar("A")
  File "C:\pypy\testParar.py", line 12, in parar
    handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_window(title_re=appname)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 113, in find_window
    element = find_element(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 84, in find_element
    elements = find_elements(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 283, in find_elements
    elements = [elem for elem in elements if _title_match(elem)]
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 283, in <listcomp>
    elements = [elem for elem in elements if _title_match(elem)]
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 279, in _title_match
    t = w.rich_text
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\win32_element_info.py", line 83, in rich_text
    return handleprops.text(self.handle)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\handleprops.py", line 92, in text
    buffer_ = create_unicode_buffer(length)
  File "C:\Python\lib\ctypes\_init_.py", line 297, in create_unicode_buffer
    buf = buftype()
MemoryError

I took the same code used in another PC running win 10 where it was working properly, and used it in win 11. The systems both have 32 Gb of Ram.
I google to try to find similar questions but only found one and there was no answer to the problem.

It is very interesting. I see it first time. Please try app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title_re=appname, timeout=5) instead of find_window and subsequent line. And which Python version do you use?

Hello and thank you for your help
I have tried and it seems to work, but I had to import Application and I had to change send_keystrokes to type_keys though, otherwise I was getting the error:
Error : AttributeError: Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'send_keystrokes' were found (typo?)
I don't know if to change all instances of send_keystrokes to type_keys now to solve the problem (I control many of these windows this way). But I don't understand why the first issue is happening, since it's working perfectly on two other computers on windows 10.

I cannot change it to this method since it does not work on non-active desktops (I was controlling multiple windows in multiple desktops).

Python version: 3.10.7

It seems like some issue in one of the applications at the whole desktop. Actual text length seems longer than it was returned by previous handler which tells the length to pywinauto. If I could reproduce it on my side, I'd say it with more confidence. Also there are other tricks in Remote Execution Guide, hope it is useful.

Is there a way I can identify the application externally/manually ?
It's a new clean installation of Windows 11 Pro. Although I did install drivers and some apps that the laptop needs (MSI things).
Thank you, but I meant windows virtual desktops, not remote ones. Running the code in a virtual desktop does not find the window in another virtual desktop, like it does with my other computers.

I can suggest only closing all windows as much as possible on this virtual desktop. Maybe it is Firefox itself or some other app. Regarding access to other virtual desktops I've recently heard about pyvda package, but it is not integrated with pywinauto at the moment. I guess pywinauto needs some changes to use non-default virtual desktop.

I tried to run the code alone with no windows at all and I still get the error (instead of not being able to find the specific window). It seems related to backend win32 and to ctypes.
I am actually using pyvda to have buttons to switch between desktops with a click !
The only thing I could do is to use it to specifically switch to the desired desktop before running the solution you proposed. But it is slow and painful, when I am doing it without switch and instantly in my other computers :(
Since it's linked to ctypes, I tried installing a different Visual c++ version to no avail...

I just identified the culprit, thank you so much for your insights !
It was SteelSeriesGG.exe app for the keyboard (bloatware **** ...), even in the tray it was somehow messing with it.

I just identified the culprit, thank you so much for your insights Vasily Ryabov ! It was SteelSeriesGG.exe app for the keyboard (bloatware **** ...), even in the tray it was somehow messing with it.

Great! You can mark your own answer as accepted (at the left side there is a gray check which should work for you). It will save some time to others so they know the problem is already solved.

This is very funny! I never thought that pywinauto will work as an antivirus. :D

For real hahaha, the thing is, it came in the drivers section of the manufacturer's page that'll teach me to leave bloatware
