pywinauto automation worked relatively fast, but now is very slow with no changes to my script
I'm making a pywinauto program to automate tasks in a benchmarking program. It will not work with the 'win32' backend because it has some special control-types, thus I have stuck with 'uia'. For the past few weeks, the program has worked somewhat fine with few pywinauto bugs. However, I have noticed that over time, starting the program over and over (due to debugging and the occasional error), it will suddenly slow down for about 1-2 minutes per operation until I restart my computer.
More specifically, when this happens, every pywinauto searching operation slows down significantly. For example, calling dialog.child_window() begins to take almost exactly 60 seconds each time it is called (with and without timeouts). I've read up on the ways to speed it up, such as control-type, class-name, and wrapper objects, but this has not changed the speed at all since I had already been doing this in my code. The application itself has <200 identifiers, so I don't believe it's a size issue either.
To re-iterate, this would only happen after I've been debugging the program for many hours and it failed to close the app after so many times. Restarting my computer has been a working solution up until now. As of recent, it is always slow per every search (child_window) operation, even after a restart. Before, the entire program would complete its automation in about 15-20 seconds. Now, it takes almost 15-20 minutes.
Finally, I am unsure whether it has to do with how I connect to the application, but I believe this may not be the cause of my problems as this same line worked fine a week ago.
myApp = Application(backend='uia', allow_magic_lookup=False).connect(title="Benchmark - GUI 1.2.1", timeout=45)
This line takes about 60 seconds to connect to my window, regardless of what the timeout time is. I have also tried starting the application, then connecting to it, with no difference in time. Subsequently, every line that has to find an identifier will take a similar amount of time.
This problem really has me stumped since it worked perfectly fine for the past few weeks, so sorry if this post is ramble-y haha. I've skimmed through a handful of the github posts, but I haven't come across one that has a solution that has worked for me. One thing I did notice when reinstalled was the clear_comtypes_cache package giving a warning about its directory not being in PATH, but again I am unsure if this is the cause or at all related.
Here are the solutions I have tried:

adding specifics to child_window() such as control_type, title, top_level_only, etc
restarting my computer each time this occurs (doesn't work anymore)
reverting windows updates to before this problem was prominent
similarly, checking for windows updates
reinstalling pywinauto
wrapper objects to hold objects used many times
buffering when the app starts and when it connects
attempting to automate a different application to see if it's app specific
clearing caches

As stated, restarting my computer was a solution up until now. As of now, I have restarted my computer a handful of times and the problem still persists. Next, when it slows, using wrapper objects reduces the time to about 1 minute per operation. Every other attempt hasn't gotten me anywhere.
I hope I have provided sufficient information about what I have tried and what my problem is. I will gladly provide more information as needed. Any input, suggestions, ways I could troubleshoot would greatly be appreciated. Thanks! :)
EDIT:
After posting this, I left for lunch and came back to my computer and it worked perfectly fine haha. However, my question still remains as this doesn't mean the problem is resolved, because it still occurs after long periods of starting and stopping without a restart.

The question is too broad. Please narrow down the issue or provide a minimal reproducible example.

To me the question is totally valid. Application(...).connect(...) walks all application windows in the system, even invisible ones. So I'd suggest to check which other programs run at the same time. For example, here we could find the bloatware: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78344344/3648361 Maybe dumping all processes with tasklist tool could be useful or something like that. Also [w.window_text() for w in Desktop(backend="uia").windows()] can help.

Another possible reason is some issues on the application side like bug in GUI framework. For example, few years ago specific version of Qt had bug with infinite hierarchy of widgets repeated / referenced recursively. Such issue could be caught by calling dialog.dump_tree() which may work few minutes or even hang in such abnormal cases. To avoid overhead of printing to console there is a parameter to write the hierarchy into text file.

@VasilyRyabov Sound great, I'll keep that in mind next time this occurs and report back if I make any discoveries. Thank you!
